# Rendering at 256*224 without blur/image filtering

Tags: rendering, resolution

I'm quite new to Blender and I've been using it to make digital art and animation in the style of old PS1/N64 games.

I was trying to render a frame at 256*224, and while in the render dialog window it seemed fine, when I opened the exported image elsewhere, instead of the sharp pixelated look I'm going for, the image just looks faded and blurry.

I did an A/B between a screenshot I took of the render dialog and the image itself, and you can definitely see one is sharper while the other is blurry. I'm still new to a lot of this but my amateur opinion tells me it might have to do with mip-mapping or texture/image filtering on render, but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated! I've attached the A/B images below.

[image: Render A/Exported File]

[image: Render B/Snipping Tool]

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)